# html5 <audio> tag don't work in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, audio

Why doesn't my `audio` tag play in Internet Explorer 11?
It works just fine in Google Chrome.
Here is my HTML:

```
<audio autoplay src="fail.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [html5test](http://html5test.com) for IE 11 the audio element should be fully supported, though the `Web Audio API` is not, which might be the problem in your case.

Comment: Yes, I have tested my IE11. Audio tag was disabled.
I have installed media pack for windows and it started to work just fine.
Thx for the test link (html5test).