# Is there any alternative for Html 5 audio element for Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html5-audio

There are a lot of discussion to explicitly indicate html 5 audio element is not supported by Internet Explorer 11 (strangely, it can be supported by both its ancestors or successors) on some Windows versions. I don't know what the reason behind is.

The discussions can be easily found by Googling "html5 audio ie11".
For example:
[<audio> tag is not working in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34802319/audio-tag-is-not-working-in-ie11)
[html5 <audio> tag don't work in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32414839/html5-audio-tag-dont-work-in-ie11)

However, I am facing a situation many of my users are exactly using IE 11 and I cannot push all of them to change it. This means they cannot use one of my music list website.

I know there is a solution to install a media pack. However, again, I cannot push each of my user to do that. Some suggests I go back to Flash, which is definitely NOT what I want. Is there anyway to achieve this by some script, e.g. javascript?

So, is there any alternative for html 5 audio element that can work in IE 11 in this situation?

Comment: "There are a lot of discussion to explicitly indicate html 5 audio element is not supported by Internet Explorer 11" Where is this discussion? It's definitely supported in IE11: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

Comment: I edited my question and provided some discussion examples. Anyway, it is not hard to know that if you perform a quick Googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE11 [**does** support HTML5 audio](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio). Microsoft's knowledge base indicates that the specific [Windows N and KN variants have all multimedia support removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2929699) (as well as a bunch of other features that won't work) and indicates the solution is to install the Media Feature Pack for N and KN editions of Windows 8.1.

Barring that, you're probably looking at needing [a Flash fallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh550090.aspx).

> As I mentioned, `<audio>` fallback content can include HTML. **And that means it can include a Flash `<object>` for browsers that don’t support `<audio>`.**

Comment: If I check my system information, it shows Windows 10 Pro. It doesn't say N or KN. But I do live in Europe. Does it mean I am using a N?

Comment: @JohnZhang It appears N is sold in Europe for regulatory reasons, and KN in South Korea for similar reasons. So, yes, you got a neutered version. Complain to the EU. :-p